# Malloc 'ing array of struct in struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've been doing research for a while, and I'm not finding anything that helps me.

I have the following struct declarations:

```
typedef struct position_struct{
    int x;
    int y;
} pos;

typedef struct item_struct{
    char member1;
    pos member2;
} item;

typedef struct room_stuct{
    item * member3;
    pos * member4;
    pos member5;
} roomLayout;
```

And the code to try to malloc it is (I removed the error checking for brevity):

```
 roomLayout *genFloor () {
                                                         // Allocate mem for Arrays of:
    roomLayout * room = malloc(sizeof(roomLayout) * 6 ); //     6 rooms
    room->member3     = malloc(sizeof(item)       * 10); //     10 member3's
    room->member4     = malloc(sizeof(pos)        * 10); //     10 member4's

    /* TESTING */
    room[0].member3[0].member1 = 'd';
    printf("Room[0] is good\n");
    room[1].member3[0].member1 = 'd';
    printf("Room[1] is good\n");           // Never prints/makes it to this line


    return room;
 }
```

When I try this, assigning to room[1] causes a crash, but not room[0]. My guess is that I havent actually allocated enough space for the whole array and only one spot. But I don't understand why as I believe that I'm following what I see everywhere else.

If someone could please explain to me the procedure for allocating memory for this kind of setup, that would be very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) might interest you.

Comment: Stop treating Array as Pointer. You never allocate memory for an Array not even for a Pointer. You allocate a memory block an you use a Pointer to point there. Please explain me how does your "Array" pointing there ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only allocating `member3` and `member4` for the first `room`; not for all of them. In the line `room->member3`, `room` is at the beginning of the memory segment, or at `room[0]`, which allocates space for 10 member3s. `room[1]`, however, has not allocated any space for any member3s (similarly for doors). Work around this by allocating in a loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    room[i].member3 = malloc(sizeof(room[i].member3) * 10);
    room[i].member4 = malloc(sizeof(room[i].member4) * 10);
}
```

When `free`-ing the memory, remember to use a similar loop, i.e.

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    free(room[i].member3);
    free(room[i].member4);
}

free(room);
```

Comment: Thats what I figured, I just didn't know how to fix it. Thanks! I couldn't find anyone doing a for loop anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

```
room->groundItems = malloc(sizeof(item) * 10);
```

The code above allocate a `10` items for only for `room[0]`.

`room[1 to 5]` are not allocated and access them is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You must allocate all your pointers before to access them, like showed below

```
roomLayout * room = malloc(sizeof(roomLayout) * 6 )
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    room[i].groundItems = malloc(sizeof(item) * 10); //     10 ground items
    room[i].doors       = malloc(sizeof(pos)  * 10); //     10 doors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocated `groundItems` and `doors` only for the first room, But you have to allocate it for all 6 rooms. Each room needs its own list of `groundItems` and `doors`. Adapt your code like this:

```
roomLayout * room = malloc(sizeof(roomLayout) * 6 ); //     6 rooms
for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i ++ )
{
    room[i].groundItems = malloc(sizeof(item)       * 10); //     10 ground items
    room[i].doors       = malloc(sizeof(pos)        * 10); //     10 doors
}
```

Note `room->groundItems` is similar to `room[0].groundItems`. So in your case `room[0].groundItems[0].objectID` worked, but `room[1].groundItems[0].objectID` failed, because `room[1].groundItems` was never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing allocation to `room[1]`, `room[2]` and so on.
by
`room->groundItems = malloc...` you implcitly say
`room[0].groundItems = malloc ...`.

Maybe the allocation of six places of `roomLayout` confused you. It allocated the pointers to `groundItems` and `doors` arrays, but  not the space they required themselves.